# Delegation lost when back to ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, uinavigationcontroller

In my program have two view controller.
first one has table view.
when i click one cell, relevant inflammations show in second view controller.
it work well.

when i go back to first view controller.click again cell now it not working.
delegation not working that time.
i navigate like this

```
-(void)gotoviewUnfinishedMinute
{
    NSArray *vc=[self.navigationController viewControllers];

    ViewControllerView *vcView=nil;

    for (int i=0; i<[vc count]; i++)
    {
        UIViewController *tempVC=[vc objectAtIndex:i];
        if([tempVC isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerView class]])
        {
            vcView=[vc objectAtIndex:i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if(vcView)
    {
        [vcView setMeetingMinute:[unfinishedMinutes objectAtIndex:selectedRow]];
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:vcView animated:NO];
        vcView = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewControllerView *vc3New = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vcview"];
        [vc3New setMeetingMinute:[unfinishedMinutes objectAtIndex:selectedRow]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3New animated:NO];
        vc3New = nil;
    }
    vc = nil;
}
```

table view delegation like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.tableViewLastMinutes.dataSource = self;
        self.tableViewLastMinutes.delegate = self;
}
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Did you check it by placing a checkpoint in the didSelect delegate method

Comment: yes this function not calling.when i click cell

Comment: Strange way to navigate between view controller while using a storyboard... Have you consider using a navigation controller with a UITableViewController as root view controller, and add a segue between this table view controller and your second view controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign delegates in `-viewWillAppear`.
ViewDidLoad calls only when the view is loaded.when popped it is not called

`viewDidLoad` is called exactly once, when the view controller is first loaded into memory. This is where you want to instantiate any instance variables and build any views that live for the entire lifecycle of this view controller.

`viewWillAppear` is called when the view is made visible, and can be called multiple times during the lifecycle of a View Controller

[See the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can check this method by placing breakpoint that they call this method or not if call for all other cells you clicked then check your indexpath where you clicked either they have value or not by placing NSLog.

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath